# Using LinkedList<> in C#

Tags: c#

I am looking to use the C# Linked list class instead of creating my own, but I'm not sure how to stick multiple items in the `LinkedList<>`.

I would like to do something like `LinkedList<string, List>`, to allow me to have:

```
entry1->string
```

And also have a List:

```
entry2->string, and list
```

All I see online from tutorials it that it will allow LinkedList only,

Any ideas on how to get more than 1 value in my linked list? Thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "entry1->string". Your whole question is basically unclear, I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you saying that each entry in the list would have a String and also another List?

Comment: entry2->string?  That's not C#, that's C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess what you mean...
You need to create a custom object for your list..

```
public class MyListItem
{
    public String s;
    public List<Something> list;
}
```

Then you can do

```
LinkedList<MyListItem> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<MyListItem>();
```

Now each item in your LinkedList has a String and a List.

You can add an item with something like

```
MyListItem myListItem = new MyListItem();
myListItem.s = "a string";
myListItem.list = someList;
myLinkedList.AddLast(myListItem);
```

Comment: How would you add an item to this? mylinkedlist.addlast(?)

Comment: Ha i do, i just can't figure out what the parameters should be, addlast("str1", list) won't work. Looks like it is expecting a MyListItem, instead of variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
Dictionary<String,List<Something>>
```

Comment: I bet this is the thing he was looking for, but people from C++ tend to ignore the dictionary type :-P